# Flutter advanced l10n

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

```json
{
    "helloWorldOn": "Hello World on {date}",
    "@helloWorldOn": {
      "description": "A message with a date parameter",
      "placeholders": {
        "date": {
          "type": "DateTime",
          "format": "yMd"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I have two question

1- How can I extend formatter to add additional calendar and formats, like `jyjMjd` for `jalaali` calendar, Consider that I want to add additional formatter, I passed an `DateTime` as argument and the formatter decides about calendar

2- How can I support additional `type`, i.e. my own defined classes

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution:

```json
{
  "helloWorldOn": "Hello World on {date}",
  "@helloWorldOn": {
    "description": "A message with a date parameter",
    "placeholders": {
      "date": {
        "type": "DateTime",
        "format": "yMd",
        "isCustomDateFormat": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Isaudon consider that I told that the formatter decides about the calendar, I don't want format it in argument

Comment: @WebMaster No worries. I'm just telling you that I couldn't do what you asked, and I had to do what I did.